# Array Of Linked Lists (5 Queues)

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, queue, singly-linked-list

I would like to implement an array of linked lists to create a printing queue; with an array of five queues. Each queue is meant to represent a user printing a job sent to the printer.

This is the code I currently have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    float value;
    struct node *next;
};

node *head = NULL;

node* A[5];

int insertNodes(node *head, int value)
{
    node *aNode, *Ptr;

    aNode = new node;
    aNode->value = value;
    aNode->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = aNode;
    else
    {
        Ptr = head;

        while (Ptr->next != NULL)
            Ptr = Ptr->next;

        Ptr->next = Ptr;
    }

    return head;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int num;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Insert number";
        cin >> num;

        A[i] = insertNodes(i, num)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not work as intended, as I am unable to add "jobs" to the queues.
Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of issues with your code:

1. You are programming in C++, not C, so instead of `struct node *next` you should simply write `node *next`.
2. Your `insertNodes` function returns a pointer to the head of the list, so you need to return `node*`, not `int`.
3. When you insert into a list with an existing head, you never insert the item. You have to do `Ptr->next = aNode`, not `Ptr->next = Ptr`.
4. In your main function, you are expected to pass a pointer to the head of the list to `insertNodes`, but you actually pass it an `int`. Instead, try `A[i] = insertNodes(A[i], num)`.
5. You store `float` in your list nodes, but input `int` - is that actually desired?

However, since you are in C++, you can probably avoid most of these pitfalls entirely by relying on what the standard library already provides.

Simply `#include <deque>` and you can use everything that [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) (a **d**ouble-**e**nded **que**ue) provides, including `push_back` to add elements at the end, `front` to access the first element, and `pop_front` to remove it - a real queue, no need for custom linked lists:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::deque<float>> A {5};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float input;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Insert number: ";
        std::cin >> input;
        A[i].push_back(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```